# How can I check if a CLI program is waiting for input from stdin?

Tags: c, windows, api, stdin

How can I check if a CLI program, that I just started with CreateProcess(), is waiting for input from stdin with the Windows C API?

Comment: Check from where? The creating program? The console?

Comment: What are you waiting for? Is this so you can send input or are you doing some sort of interactive input?

Comment: You don't, you redesign your parent program.  You either (a) let it inherit your standard input and do nothing or (b) create a pipe for it, feed it your desired input, and close the pipe.  But you have to be careful to avoid deadlock, if the program also produces output, by either using multiple threads or careful usage of non-blocking I/O and `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: No. I just need to now WHEN the created process needs input, I don't have any input for it. Then I send this information to a remote web application, so that a remote user can interact with the created process. I hope I am clear now, haha!

Comment: You'll have to modify the child program so that it tells you when it is ready for input.  You could do this in a number of ways, for one example, look up the CreateEvent function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as some of the comments above have said, you cannot check if your program is waiting for stdin once it has already started waiting.  You could use an event handler or you could simply have a read from stdin with a timeout, where on occurrence of the timeout you flag that you are waiting for input and start waiting with a timeout again.