# How to check if a process has filled the STDOUT or STDERR buffer

Tags: linux, debugging, command-line

Given a process on a Linux machine which appears to be stuck, how can I tell if it is stuck due to the STDOUT or STDERR buffer being full?

In my particular case, I have a process which is performing no CPU activity, but remains running when I would expect it to have exited within a few seconds. My suspicion is that the process has filled up the buffer for STDOUT or STDERR and the process which is supposed to be reading from that the buffer has stopped doing so for some reason.

Is there any way I can confirm this suspicion?

Comment: An alternate theory if that doesn't pan out - Can I check if the process is blocked waiting for input on STDIN somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Attaching gdb and running backtrace pretty much confirms my theory...

```
$ gdb /opt/our_process pid
...blah blah blah...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003f27adae60 in __write_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003f27a71583 in _IO_new_file_write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003f27a7144a in _IO_new_file_xsputn () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003f27a49531 in buffered_vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000003f27a4449e in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000003f27a4f03a in printf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
...out process's stack...
```

And strace as [shelter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14432284/797) also seems like it would do the trick...

```
$ strace -p 27689
Process 27689 attached - interrupt to quit
write(1, "some_text"..., 293
```

Comment: so is this the answer? or more evidence for people to work with? :-) Good luck.

Comment: From my point of view I think I've confirmed my theory (and I'll accept this answer when the two day waiting period is up) unless someone provides a more complete/thorough one :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a std linux process, a specially installed 3rd party package or custom written code ?

Std linux processes should have no such issues, while custom code is the most likely culprit. The easiest way to debug that situation is to add special debugging code.

Else, look to see if  your std utility or 3rd-party package has a verbose mode, often `-v, or -vv, or -vvv`.

Finally you can use your OS's version of `truss (for solaris)` , `strace` for some Linux versions, to see where it is hanging.

IHTH

Comment: It's a C process developed in house here, which has been launched by some Java code (again, of our own design), but it's not a reproducible situation, so I'm trying to get what info I can from the already running process before I kill it off.

Comment: Actually, while -v, etc are interesting, `strace` can practically always take to right where it is hanging (by function name), the problem is, often times you can tell which of 100 places that `printf` (for example) in your code it is being called from. Hopefully the arguments and values you see associated will give you an idea of which  line in your  code base is hanging. High probability in an enterprise level system are a particular drive in a disk cluster. Good luk.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your alternate theory, have a look at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803122/how-can-i-check-if-a-cli-program-is-waiting-for-input-from-stdin). I found [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) interesting, I hope something here is useful. CHEERS

Comment: Have you tried pidstat?  (: http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/pidstat) shows you how you might be able to use it to get some information about I/O issues and other things about your process if you have a modern kernel and you are set up correctly. CHEERS